# Loop "flash" animation 3 times, then delay 5 seconds, loop again with Animate.css

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

Really like the look of Animate.css, just trying to configure the "flash" feature.

I have added an extra class (.promptflash).

How can I perform the flash for 3 times, then delay for 5 seconds and repeat the loop 3 times, then delay..repeat...

Also trying to slow the initial flash animation down a bit as it flashes quite fast by default

[Animate.CSS - List of features](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

```
.promptflash {
animation: 0.3s infinite;
animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tebg9by/) for that. It's without -webkit and -moz prefixes just to show you how you can make that.

```
.flash {
  -webkit-animation-name: move;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration:6s;

}

@keyframes move{
  0% { opacity: 0;}
  5% { opacity: 1;}
  10% { opacity: 0;}
  15% { opacity: 1;}
  20% { opacity: 0;}
  25% { opacity: 1;}
 }
```

Comment: Strangely, it works in JSFiddle. But within my Ionic app, there is no delay. It just loops continuous https://jsfiddle.net/w02p5w4n/

Comment: then just change the class name in your div and change again in your css or just add  animation-name: move!important; and you should give the class infinite to your div because in your js fiddle you don't have that class